# WordPress Password Reset link is invalid on localhost using XAMPP

Tags: wordpress

I have a fresh install of WordPress on my localhost and using XAMPP as my virtual webserver. After installing and logging out, it then asked me to confirm my account using a confirmation email. The problem is that smtp isn't working through sendmail on XAMPP so I cannot receive the confirmation email.

As a workaround I added the following line in my functions.php file to bypass this confirmation step.
add_filter( 'admin_email_check_interval', '__return_false' );

After logging in, I installed WP Mail SMTP plugin to handle emails for my WordPress installation. I logged out, removed the above line from functions.php, then tried the Forgot Password link to reset my password. I successfully received the email to my webmail account, but when I click on the link I receive the following error message in my WordPress site:

"Error: Your password reset link appears to be invalid. Please request a new link below."

Here is the link in the email with my personal info substituted:
http://127.0.0.1/mywebsite/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=4I6Io2cMhFoqPHT4Ivg8&login=myusername&wp_lang=en_US

When I look at the users table in phpmyadmin and edit the single admin user account, I noticed there isn't anything in the user_activation_key field, even though I used the Forgot Password link to reset the password -- not sure if this has anything to do with it.

I also tried substituting 127.0.0.1 with localhost but same result.

Is there any reason why this password reset link wouldn't work on my localhost?

Answer (score 0):

After additional investigation, realized I forgot to remove the following line at the bottom of the wp-login.php to reset the admin password:

wp_set_password('yournewpassword',1);

Now works, can login and get passed the admin email confirmation